# Error of creating bean :injectionof autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to spring boot, I'm building an application using these technologies with Maven and JPA annotation, this  error occured while executing my project. here is 
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr8OZ.png)

[Application Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WFB0.png)

[the repository interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaGMc.png) 
[the implementing class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Z7t.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of pictures, consider writing the code and errors, so that anyone can reproduce the error.

Comment: i'm new in StackOverflow, idon't know how to write codes in here !

Comment: Please read this page before posting questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some points that you can work on:

- Spring boot auto configuration do the automatic scan of Spring beans
  so you can delete the `@ComponentScan` annotation (supposed that you're new so you use relatively lastest version).
- you don't need the SalleRepoImpl (at list now as your use case is basic "save") by extending `JpaRepository<Salle, Long>` you have what you need (eg: findOne, findBy.., findAll)
  please refer to [the officiel documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods).
- The use of `@Qualifier` annotation is useless in you case and probably the cause of your error.

> The qualifier annotation helps disambiguate bean references when
>   Spring would otherwise not be able to do so.

For more detail, please refert to the [official documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier).

Hope it was helpful :)

Comment: Thank you i will try this now and see if it will work

Comment: I've just tried what you've noticed but in vain, it  still the same problem

Comment: I should to build this application this week and i don't really have enough time to do it as i'm new to Spring Boot so i find myself stuck here, if you can help me guys to move on this i would be so grateful

Comment: send me your skype id by email: montassarelbehi@gmail.com I 'll see it with you once at home.

Comment: i've sent you a mail